# How to test if method that takes argument is throwing an exception in dart?

Tags: testing, dart

If I have

```
class ErrorThrower{
  void throwAnError(String argument){
    throw new Error();
  }
}
```

I want to test if throwAnError throws Exception, or more precisely an instance of `Error`

This is my code but it doesn't work

```
  test('', () {
    var errorThrower = new ErrorThrower();
    expect(errorThrower.throwAnError("string"), throwsException);
  });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dart's testing package can detect errors thrown, but the function either needs to be asynchronous (most commonly, return a `Future`), or be provided as a callback, so the `expect` function can lazily evaluate it. In your example:

```
test('', () {
  var errorThrower = new ErrorThrower();
  expect() => errorThrower.throwAnError("string"), throwsError);
});
```

... should work. Note that I wrote `throwsError` not `throwsException`, in Dart these are two different things (that do not inherit from each other), with the intention that errors are not intentionally caught in production code, but exceptions (such as `FormatException`) should be.

Comment: right on!! ```test("expect an error", (){ expect( ()=>pingException(), throwsException ); });```